# QuerySet filter with multiple ManyToMany field lookups does not behave as expected

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I am trying to write a simple Django filter which doesn't seem to work as expected. I have a `User` model and a `Vacation` model and I want to write a query to get all users that are not on vacation.

```py
class User(models.Model):
    vacation = models.ManyToManyField('Vacation')


class Vacation(models.Model):
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField()
```

The obvious solution I tried was:

```py
now = timezone.now()

User.objects.exclude(vacation__start__lte=now, vacation__end__gt=now)
```

This doesn't work. This queryset will also exclude any `User` objects that have a future vacation (start time and end time after `now`). I think this is a result of the combination of the exclude and the many to many lookup but I can't find any documentation on why this behaves this way and there doesn't seem to be a way to get to the simple result using simple queryset chain. The only way I've got this to work is by querying `User` objects on vacation and then running another queryset excluding users with those IDs. Ex:

```py
users_on_vacation = User.objects.filter(vacation__end__gte=now, vacation__start__lte=now).values_list('pk', flat=True)
users_not_on_vacation = User.objects.exclude(pk__in=users_on_vacation)
```

Is there a simpler way to write this filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships (the second note in particular).  You'll see exclude behaves slightly differently to filter when applying criteria to 'each' in a m2m set rather than 'any'.

The way round provided on that page, fitted to your case,  would look something like:

```
User.objects.exclude(
    vacation__in = Vacation.objects.filter(
         start__lte=now, 
         end__gt=now
    ),
)
```

Comment: Any idea why this is implemented differently for exclude? It seems unintuitive.

Comment: There's some discussion of it here: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14645 - looks like some attempts were made, but ultiamtely the docs where changed to point out the anomaly.